# Ubuntu 16.04 fullscreen online videos freeze very often, offline no

Tags: video

I'm using firefox and I can't see online video on fullscreen. I have installed flash player from the official site, and I have the plugin enabled.

Offline (downloaded video) everything is alright. I have this problem on YouTube and also on other websites. Any video in fullscreen online doesn't work. I'm using the onboard output and not the GPU. 
I have 2 plugins in firefox and i tried every possibilities disabling and/or enabling both, none or one yes and one no.

[image: plugins]

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'  

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0402] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [1849:0402]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c02] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c02]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_390, nvidia_390_drm
```

The problem was a program (ethminer) without that program running i don' t get any problems watching video online. After moving my home partition to another hard disk even with that program i can see video online.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving#Setup_Partitions only at some point it required me to use ctrl+alt+f1 because although the home partition was mounted and so i cannot perform a command. In the guide that was missing.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? On which website(s) do you experience this issue? Can you provide a link to an example video? Did you try without Flash Player enabled? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Disabled / enabled hardware acceleration? Many (most?) sites use html5 video now

Comment: How i can do that?

Comment: Could you please disable Flash Player and try again just to make sure that it doesn't interfere? Could you please also [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so far. What happens when you try to play back Youtube videos with the Shockwave Flash plug-in disabled?

Comment: I get the same unwatchable video that i get with the Shockwave Flash plug-in enabled